# How do you create a function representing the english word "or" in python?

Tags: python

I need "or" in the sentence if a ~or~ b>=0:
If there is really no solution, I'd be glad to be provided with alternative solutions to my problem if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: We need more details. What is the input and output? Are your trying to implement a logic `def or(a, b):` function? Or a `if a >= 0 or b >= 0:`?

Answer (score 3):

```
def function(a,b):
    if a >= 0 or b >= 0:
        #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to construct a boolean:

```
if a >= 0 or b >= 0:
```

Comment: nevermind, Gabriel's answer is more correct, cause you asked for a function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

`if a >= 0 or b >= 0`

Comment: except if one is more negative than the other is positive....